# Ruby. Class vs instance variable methods

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have a class:

```
class MyClass
  def self.create_array
    variable = ['one', 'two', 'three']

    # I had:
    # variable.each {|v| v.upcase}
    # but want to do:

    second_method(variable)
    # or like this:
    variable.second_method
    # of course without parameter 'var' in second option
  end

  def second_method (var)
    var.map {|v| v.upcase}
  end
end


puts MyClass.create_array
# of course:
=> undefined method `second_method' for MyClass:Class (NoMethodError)
```

So I am just wondering how to incorporate second_method into first one.

It only worked when I did:

```
class MyClass
  def self.create_array
    variable = ['one', 'two', 'three']

    MyClass.second_method(variable)
  end

  def self.second_method (var)
    var.map {|v| v.upcase}
  end
end


puts MyClass.create_array
```

Why it works only when I call it on class? I would like to just call it on my variable. Please, enlighten me!

### Edit

Would it make any sense to create method in:

```
class Array
  def second_method
    #content
  end
end
```

Comment: second_method can not be called inside a class method, cause it lacks an instance. Methods of a class always needs an instance of the class, otherwise you can not call it.

Read also this http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Comment: wouldn't do the monkeypatching of class Array, that's gonna give errors when called on arrays that contain non-strings, also it is a functionality needed in your class, not in array

Comment: @peter so I will follow your advices below then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `second_method` as an instance method on `MyClass`, which means it can only be called on an instance of `MyClass` - not on the class itself (that's why the second version works, where you define both methods as class methods using the `self.` operator.

To get your existing code to work, you could call `MyClass.new.second_method(variable)` inside `self.create_array`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby only class methods can be called from an class method. when you are calling `create_array` in first snippet, you can not call a instance methds from inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others pointed out, class methods can only be called directly on the class itself.

Is it this you want to achieve ?

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :variable

  def initialize
    @variable = ['one', 'two', 'three']
    second_method @variable
  end

  def second_method var
    @variable = var.map {|v| v.upcase}
  end
end


MyClass.new

#<MyClass:0x292fda0 @variable=["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]>
```

Or you can give the array as a parameters when instantiating the class like this

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :variable

  def initialize variable
    @variable = variable
    second_method @variable
  end

  def second_method var
    @variable = var.map {|v| v.upcase}
  end
end


MyClass.new ['one', 'two', 'three']

#<MyClass:0x292fda0 @variable=["ONE", "TWO", "THREE"]>
```

Comment: It looks like something I want to achieve. But I'm not sure if I can initialize my array. Need to test it on my code. Thank you for a hint.

Comment: you can give the array as parameter when instantiating your class, added that in the answer, also forgot to store the result of second_method to @variable

Comment: My code is a bit more complex.. I need a while to test it. In meantime it would be great if you could take a look at my question in edit section =)